# python how to add text to a oval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Im making a "math bubble" game in python 3.3, its where ovals(bubbles) move around randomly on the canvas, These bubbles have a number on them e.g.2 and the user must pop/click the bubbles in relation to the question e.g. Multiples of 2, user will click bubbles that say 2,4,6,8 etc.

Trouble is, I dont know how or if its possible to put a number on an oval Ive created.
Please help me >.<

Code so far:

## Math Bubbles

```
from tkinter import *
import random


def quit():
    root.destroy()


def bubble():
    xval = random.randint(5,765)
    yval = random.randint(5,615)
    canvas.create_oval(xval,yval,xval+30,yval+30,   fill="#00ffff",outline="#00bfff",width=5)
    canvas.update()

def main():
    global root
    global tkinter
    global canvas
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Math Bubbles")
    Button(root, text="Quit", width=8, command=quit).pack()
    Button(root, text="Start", width=8, command=bubble).pack()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=650, bg = '#afeeee')
    canvas.pack()
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put text in a tkinter canvas, use the create_text method.  To place it on an oval you make, set the position to be the center of the oval.  In this case, the center of each oval you make is (xval+15, yval+15).  See below:

```
def bubble():
    xval = random.randint(5,765)
    yval = random.randint(5,615)
    canvas.create_oval(xval,yval,xval+30,yval+30, fill="#00ffff",outline="#00bfff",width=5)
    canvas.create_text(xval+15,yval+15,text="mytext")
    canvas.update()
```

Each oval you now make will have "mytext" written in it.

However, you might want to look into animation software for more complex applications involving movement.  Some good examples are Pygame and Livewires.  But that is up to you.

Comment: for simply moving ovals around on a screen, Tkinter is quite sufficient. Also, you don't need the call to `update`, as that happens automatically once the event loop is entered. Finally, you might want to give both the oval and the text inside identical tags, so they can be moved as a single unit.

Comment: @BryanOakley: My goal was to just show the OP how to do what he wanted, not refactor his code entirely.  Had I built the system myself, I would have used a class and whatnot.  Also, I mentioned Pygame and such because I don't know the complexity he is planning.  I was trying to say that, if he intends to build a very sophisticated game, tkinter might be too weak to do it nicely.  Nevertheless, you make very good points and I agree with each one.

Comment: @LilKasian: You're welcome!  Remember, to keep the text on top of the ovals, set its location to be the center of the oval.  If the ovals are moving, make sure the text moves with them and stays on top in the center.  Also, if you feel that my answer solved your problem appropriately, then you should accept it.  Otherwise, your question remains "unanswered", which can confuse people.  If it did not however, feel free to let me know and I'll be glad to help further.